# subprocess call doesn't work remotely with ipython notebook server

Tags: python, subprocess, ipython, remote-server

I used code like `subprocess.call("ruby_script.rb > output.txt", shell=True)` in my python class to run external scripts.

I have an ipython notebook server with my Ubuntu desktop machine.

On my MacBook, whenever I remotely ran cells that used class containing the above `subprocess.call` line, I got nonzero exit status, saying cannot find the directory. If I try simple command like `subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)`, I will get sth like `CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '-l']' returned non-zero exit status 2`.

On my Ubuntu desktop machine, whenever I logged into the same notebook server and run the same cells, I got perfect results. If I try simple command like `subprocess.check_call(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)`, I will get sth like `0`, indicating no error at all.

I am wondering why such codes could not work remotely.

On my Ubuntu desktop machine, the server's python version is 2.7.6, while the ipython version is 2.2.0.

My MacBook's OS X version is 10.9.4 and my desktop's Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS.

Thanks!

I tried the code suggested by Charles on my MacBook by remotely logging into the nbserver, pasting the code to a cell in the notebook, and running the cell.

`import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['ls', '-l'], cwd='/')`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 import subprocess
----> 2 subprocess.check_call(['ls', '-l'], cwd='/')

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    538         if cmd is None:
    539             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 540         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    541     return 0
    542 

CalledProcessError: Command '['ls', '-l']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

By the way, it *works* if I do the same things above from the same Ubuntu desktop running the nbserver.

Comment: It's not necessarily the immediate cause of your problem, but don't use `shell=True` when passing an array; its behavior in that case is almost always different from what you actually want.

Comment: Re: "saying cannot find the directory", btw -- if you included the _exact_ error text in your question, that would be helpful. Right now, we don't know if that error is coming from `ls`, from the calling shell, or from Python.

Comment: thanks, charles. i added an error message of running the code you suggested. for running cells regarding external scripts on my macbook, i just know the exit status will be 1 for executing ruby script and will be 139 for executing compiled c program. however, there is *no* problem at all if i repeat the process on the ubuntu machine that is also hosting the nbserver.

Comment: Next thing I'd try would be ensuring that `PATH` is set. Calling `/bin/ls` explicitly is one approach. Beyond that, it'd be time to pull out `strace` and see what's actually happening on the server.

Comment: `exit status 2` means that `ls` detects a serious trouble. Try to redirect its output to a file: `check_call(["ls", "-l"], cwd="/", stdout=open('/tmp/ls.log', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: unrelated: have you tried to execute external commands in the `ipython notebook` using `! ls -l` syntax or `%%bash` magic without `subprocess`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and J.F.Sebastian, sorry for no reply for a long time. I guess I found the reason --- I didn't put the process running nbserver to background. After I doing so, It works remotely... I still don't understand why it doesn't work as a foreground running process. Thanks you two for helping me:)